# What is wrong with the conversion characters in my program? [Beginner]

Tags: c

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("I am the first %s, while I am the second % \n", "substitute", "one");
    char game1[9]="Football";
    char game2[6]="Chess";
    printf("I love %s and %s \n", game1, game2);
}
```

The output is:

```
I am the first substitute, while I am the second one
I love Football and ChessFootball
```

The second line of the output is confusing me. Why is there extra "Football" there?
Thank you.

Comment: `second % \n` typo ? --> `second %s \n`

Comment: ChessFootball sound awesome

Comment: I ran this at http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php, and the results are correct. Can you double check your code? maybe you just have a typo.

Comment: Steverbot  - This is strange, I used the website you mentioned in your comment, and the result is just fine. Although in my code-blocks it's different.

Comment: As @BLUEPIXY commented, change `second %` to `second %s`.

Comment: Perhaps your compiler isn't finishing the char arrays with a 0? Try adding a `\0` before the `"` in `game1` and `game2`.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked your code and it works fine for me, what compiler did you use? You can debug the strange behaviour by printing the last character of both strings:

```
printf("game1 last char: %d\n", game1[8]);
printf("game2 last char: %d\n", game2[5]);
```

If the two values aren't 0's then there's the problem, because when reading a string, the program reads all of the characters continuously till it encounter a null terminator (`'\0'` as a char or `0` as an int). In this case the compiler probably didn't insert a trailing null terminator in the char table. Simply add (two ways):

```
char game1[8] = '\0';
char game2[5] = 0;
```

If the two values are in fact 0's, then I do not know what it could be, but you can also initialize a string as a pointer:

```
const char *game1 = "Football";
const char *game2 = "Chess";
```

Comment: `char *game1 = "Football";` should be `const char *game1 = "Football";`. `'\n'` is not the null terminator, `'\0'` is the null terminator.

Comment: Well the pointer doesn't really have to be `const`, but yes it _should_ be. Wops a typo, my bad! Thanks or the info

Comment: the pointer don't have to be const, the `char`s have to be const, because the pointer points to a string literal. `char* const` would be a const pointer to char, `const char*` is a pointer to a const char.